# What does "sails flaming" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Narrator: Home was a condo on the 15th floor of a filing cabinet for
> widows and young  professionals. The walls were solid concrete. A foot
> of concrete's important when your next-door neighbor has to watch game
> shows at full volume. Or when a blast of debris that used to be your
> personal effects blows out of your windows and **sails flaming** into the
> night.

What does "sails flaming" mean? I know sailing boat, how can you sail flames?

Source: Fight Club (1999)

Comment: Do you know what the word "sails" means as a verb? Do you know what "flaming" means? Why didn't looking those words up in a dictionary help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more complete quotation from an online screenplay clarifies it a little:

> JACK (V.O.)
> The walls were solid concrete.  A foot of concrete is important when
> your next-door neighbor lets her hearing aid go and has to watch game
> shows at full blast ...
> The taxi turns a corner and Jack sees the front of the building.  A
> diffuse CLOUD of SMOKE wafts away from a BLOWN-OUT SECTION on the
> fifteenth floor.  FIRETRUCKS, POLICECARS and a MOB are all crowded
> around the lobby area.
> JACK (V.O.)
> **-- Or when a volcanic blast of burning gas and debris that used to be
> your furniture and personal effects blows out your floor-to-ceiling
> window and sails down flaming to leave just your condo -- only yours --
> a gutted, charred concrete hole in the cliffside of the building.**

The sense is that those materials **sail down**, because there has been an explosion in the apartment, and some of the contents thrown out the windows are on fire, that is, they are in flames, or **flaming**.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to imagine commas both before and after the word “flaming”. It is a descriptive word that can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence. The debris was sailing (flying) out of the window through a force that it did not generate. Simultaneously, the debris can be described as flaming or being in flames. Said debris just happened to formerly be the characters personal belongings.